# How to merge multiple inputs (four) into neural network for binary image classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

How would I structure a neural network for binary classification with four inputs (i.e., instead of feeding in one full image, I want to feed in four equally sized patches/tiles of the image that are labeled either class 1 or class 2).

My current implementation follows a simple sequential model for binary classes and I would like to convert this to the scheme as mentioned above.

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        r'MY\\TRAINING\\PATH',
        classes = ['Class1', 'Class2'],
        target_size=(100, 100), 
        batch_size=16,
        shuffle=False,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        r'MY\\VALIDATION\\PATH',
        classes = ['Class1', 'Class2'],
        target_size=(100, 100), 
        batch_size=8,
        # Use binary labels
        shuffle=False,
        class_mode='binary')

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 3)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
                                    ])
```

As an example, the file structure of my data would look like this:

```
├── training
│   ├── Class1_Quadrant1
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_2.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_3.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
│   ├── Class1_Quadrant2
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_2.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_3.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
│   ├── Class1_Quadrant3
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_2.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_3.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
│   ├── Class1_Quadrant4
│   │   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_2.jpg
│   │   ├── IMG_3.jpg
│   │   ├── etc.jpg
```

and have the same exact structure for my validation set.

Ideally, something similar to this image if it helps:

[image: NN Example]

**EDIT:**

```
# Input Model 1
input1 = Input(shape=(100, 100, 3))
conv11 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 4, activation = 'relu')(input1)
pool11 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(conv11)
conv12 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size = 4, activation = 'relu')(pool11)
pool12 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(conv12)
conv12 = Conv2D(8, kernel_size = 4, activation = 'relu')(pool11)
pool12 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(conv12)
flat1 = Flatten()(pool12)
dense1 = Dense(1)(flat1)

# ... same structure repeated up to Input 4


# Merge All Input Models
merge = concatenate([flat1, flat2, flat3, flat4])

# Dense layers
hidden1 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(merge)
hidden2 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(hidden2)
hidden4 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(hidden3)
output = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(hidden4)
model = Model(inputs = [input1, input2, input3, input4], outputs = output)

# Lastly my data comes from 

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(1 / 255.0)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(1 / 255.0)

train_generator1 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'training\\path\\Q1',  
    classes = ['D1', 'D2'],
    target_size = (100, 100),  
    batch_size = 16,
    shuffle = False,
    class_mode = 'binary'
    )

validation_generator1 = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'validation\\path\\Q1',  
    classes = ['D1', 'D2'],
    target_size = (100, 100), 
    batch_size = 8,
    shuffle = False,
    class_mode = 'binary'
    )

# this continues on for the 4 training and 4 validation generators
# until I get the error thrown here

model.compile(
    optimizer = tensorflow.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-4),
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['accuracy']
    )

history = model.fit(
    [train_generator1, train_generator2, train_generator3, train_generator4],  
    epochs = 100,
    verbose = 1,
    validation_data = [validation_generator1, validation_generator2, validation_generator3, validation_generator4],
    )
```

Traceback:

```
history = model.fit(
    [train_generator1, train_generator2, train_generator3, train_generator4],  
    epochs = 100,
    verbose = 1,
    validation_data = [validation_generator1, validation_generator2, validation_generator3, validation_generator4],
    )
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-332d3f7e4bba>", line 5, in <module>
    validation_data = [validation_generator1, validation_generator2, validation_generator3, validation_generator4],

  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1063, in fit
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)

  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1104, in __init__
    adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)

  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 971, in select_data_adapter
    _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: hi were you able to solve this. please let me know how it worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible with Sequential API (every layer should have one input): https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model

Try Functional API: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and started converting by using the functional API method. I now got stuck on training the model where it throws "ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>", I will add the traceback and updated code for reference in my original post.

Comment:  how do you generate labels ?

Comment: That's the reason I used the data generator, as an example, if I inspect 'train_generator1.labels', it yields an array of my labels like: array([0,0,0,...1,1,1,...]). I recently tried feeding in the model.fit() the actual numpy arrays of the images (I loaded it into four temp variables instead passing datagen's directly and it fixed this issue). 

I almost got it, there's just a size mismatch now which I am trying to resolve: ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 15488 but received input with shape [None, 964800].

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27849716)

Comment: @IvanAracki thank you for your comment. In the context of question - essential part of Functional API is that it could be used to create models with a few inputs. It is included into the answer. As you can see - it helped

Comment: @IvanAracki I don't think that this is link-only. If you remove the links, the answer is "It is impossible with Sequential API (every layer should have one input). Try [the] Functional API [instead]." This *is*, in fact, an answer the question. (Whether it's a correct or useful answer is a question for voting, not for the very low quality queue).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will have to create a model that has 4 inputs, one input  per image quadrant. Then each input can be processed independently by layers as needed. Then flatten the outputs of each of these input streams and concatenate them. Then process the concatenate layer output with a dense layer with 1 node.
the code below is sort of an idea about how to go about generating the inputs.
Have a training directory with sub directories that are the classes and put the images into those sub directories. Example below shows how to take images from the ImageDataGenerator and separate the images into quadrants.

```
# function below splits an image into 4 quadrants and returns them in imgq
def quad_split (img, width, height):
    mid_width=width//2
    mid_height=height//2
    imgq=[]
    imgq.append(img[0:mid_height, 0:mid_width])
    imgq.append(img[0:mid_height, mid_width:])
    imgq.append(img[mid_height:, 0:mid_width])
    imgq.append(img[mid_height:, mid_width:])
    return imgq
# function below just  displays the 4 quadrants 
def quad_plot(quad):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=( 10, 10))
    for i in range (4):
        imgn=(quad[i]+1)/2
        fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1)
        plt.imshow(imgn)
train_dir=r'c:\temp\people\train' # point this to your training directory
train_gen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input, horizontal_flip=True)
train_gen=train_gen.flow_from_directory( train_dir, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32, seed=123, )
# you can make similar generators for validation and test data
images, labels=next(train_gen) # fetch the next batch of images and labels
for image in images:
    quads=quad_split (image, 224, 224) # split each image into quadrants
    quad_plot(quads) # just used to display the quadrants of an image
```

You will have to build a generator that creates the 4 inputs to the model including the labels but this should not be to hard to achieve. Good luck